# Vietnam e-visa application denied with "Please provide a specific (expected) address in Vietnam"

Tags: vietnam, e-visas

I put my Vietnam e-visa application in this morning and have been checking its progress from time to time despite them saying it usually takes 3 to 6 days. But I did see an update now close to 5pm, just not what I expected:

> "Please provide a specific (expected) address in Vietnam"

In my initial application I chose the first accommodation I could find on Google Maps on the other side of the nearby border crossing I intend to use:

I put "Khu Du lịch Khoáng nóng Sơn Kim" which is the name and address, I suppose, as it's shown in Google Maps info. Google Maps has another field just below with "C6MC+5R Hương Sơn, Ha Tinh, Vietnam"

I did try to Google the place first to find more details like phone number etc but didn't find anything. I've been on the road close to two years and for every other country I've had visa waiver or visa-on-arrival and just put the name of the accommodation and it's always been fine.

So I'm allowed to amend my application and did so. This time I chose the closest one on Booking.com, which is in a proper town and used the address as listed in Booking.com:

> "Khách sạn Ngàn Phố
> 6 Đường Nguyễn Tuấn Thiện, Hương Sơn"

Should this be sufficient? My time is getting pretty tight. I have 7 days left on my Laos visa, should be enough time to get to a crossing with Thailand or Cambodia if I'm denied again. But if I have to keep retrying and I hear back once per day just before 5pm I could easily run out of days.

Does anyone have any knowledge on what exactly is required for this field and if it's known to be a problem?

Comment: If Google Translate is to be believed, your first address was "Son Kim Hot Mineral Tourist Area", which is neither hotel nor street address.  So your second attempt sounds much better.

Comment: Well that makes sense. I guess I got used to the names of accomm in Thailand and Laos in Google maps usually being right.